# How can I create a workflow from a xamlx file?

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation

I used to have a workflow service, using a xamlx file.

Now what I want to do is to create multiple workflows, and depending on the nature of the operation I want to be able to invoke WF1 or WF2.

So, I want to be able to dynamically load the xamlx and then pass it all it needs (say, a string) and then call it's initial method, say Start().

Any ideas on how to do that? I found some code that does that:

```
string workflow = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFile("WF1.xamlx")).ReadToEnd();
var dynamicActivity = ActivityXamlServices.Load(workflow) as DynamicActivity;
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(dynamicActivity);
```

though I'm not sure how it's going to behave.

Answer (score 0):

First to lines are OK. But you cannot use WorkflowInvoker to invoke Workflow Service.

[WorkflowServiceHost Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.workflowservicehost.aspx) is intended for hosting Workflow Services, and [WorkflowInvoker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.aspx) is for "regular" workflows.